# Как подключить определение лиц в Facebook?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-api

В FaceBook есть такая функция, определять лицо по фотографии, там они предлагают типо, хотите отметить (такого то человека на фото) так вот как подключить эту технологию для своего сайта, что бы мы получали ссылку на его facebook ?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял из вопроса тебе следует попробовать [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/photo/tags).

Comment: Вот ещё нашел на git'е: [Facematch](https://github.com/louisondumont/facematch)